# How do I make a div visible on another page?

Tags: html, image

Right now, I have 2 separate pages and I want to be able to click something on one page that makes an image in a div tag visible on the other page.

This is how i made my div tag invisible.
On the other page, I have an image that is clickable, and i want it to make the div visible. Help please?

Comment: what does page mean? another tab? another window? another browser?

Comment: another tab, in the same browser. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to set up some kind of web socket. When the image is clicked you'd fire off an ajax request which stores a flag in a database. The other page would be listening for that flag and when it changed the image would become visible/invisible.

[Check this out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets)

Answer (score 0):

If the first page triggers the second page to open you could use javascripts window.open() and pass in what to display

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<p>Click the button to open a new window called "MsgWindow" with some text.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Open window</button>

<script> 
    function myFunction() {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=600, height=300");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 600px wide and 300px tall!</p><div>    <img src='http://www.jyte.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/google-hummingbird.jpg' alt='nothing' />    </div>");
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

the best option would be using a web app using controllers, views, modules and services like angular where the first page controller can update the service and the second page controller would have the service injected so when the service changes it updates the scope which in turn updates the view.

other options would be using backend databases and ajax to store the click and having the second page check very second for update in the database and then update the page, but this method is really not practical (running an ajax request every second).

another option is using the browsers local storage, (not supported in all browsers) here is a link
 [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do so would be to set a cookie (or store the state in browser local storage, but that is not available everywhere) when you click your button, and have the other page poll for it.

Server-side solutions like sockets or session variables look like A-bombs swatting flies here, but that would surely improve your cool factor by a few thousand points.

This seems like a pretty weird design in the first place, but surely you have your reasons...